# How can I use the URL to set the current culture in ASP.NET 2.0 Web App?

Tags: asp.net, localization, url-rewriting, asp.net-2.0, url-routing

I am looking in to ways to enable a site to basically have something like:

http://mysite.com/**en-US**/index.aspx`

Where the "en-US" can vary by culture..

This culture in the URL will then basically set the `CurrentUICulture` for the application..

Basically, we currently have a page where the user explicitly clicks it, but some are favouriting past that, and it is causing some issues..

I know this sort of thing is easily done in ASP.NET MVC, but how about those of us still working in 2.0? Can you guys in all your wisdom offer any suggestions/pointers/ANYTHING that may get me started? This is new to me :)

I'm sure there must be some way to pick up the request and set/bounce as appropriate.. `HttpModule` maybe?

#### Update

Just had a thought.. May be best to create VirtDirs in IIS and then pull the appropriate part from the Requested URL and set the culture in `InitializeCulture`?

Comment: AFAIK, The problem with VirtDirs is that they don't share Session objects and are difficult to test.

Comment: This is only the case if the VirtDirs are set to run in their own app pool - if they are all in the same pool, session should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is storing the choice in a cookie out of the question?
Nice of you to give the users a choice but why not just default to the users client/web browser settings?

If they bookmark a page and have lost the cookie you could fall back to the default and if that is a culture you do not support then fallback further to en-US.

If you want to keep your solution you could use a rewrite engine. I've used http://www.managedfusion.com/products/url-rewriter/ in the past. For a list of engines see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine#IIS

Answer (score 1):

You can use the routing feature developed for MVC easily with webforms. This SO question addresses doing that:

[ASP.NET Routing with Web Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174849/aspnet-routing-with-web-forms)

If you can't use the 3.5 framework, there are a number of URL rewriting modules out there. I have no experience with any to be able to make a recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing it in some sites with ASP.net Routing.

Here is the code:

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Code that runs on application startup
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
End Sub


Public Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
    Dim reportRoute As Route
    Dim DefaultLang As String = "es"

    reportRoute = New Route("{lang}/{page}", New LangRouteHandler)
    '* if you want, you can contrain the values
    'reportRoute.Constraints = New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.lang = "[a-z]{2}"})
    reportRoute.Defaults = New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.lang = DefaultLang, .page = "home"})

    routes.Add(reportRoute)
End Sub
```

Then LangRouteHandler.vb class:

```
Public Class LangRouteHandler
     Implements IRouteHandler

  Public Function GetHttpHandler(ByVal requestContext As System.Web.Routing.RequestContext) As System.Web.IHttpHandler _
      Implements System.Web.Routing.IRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler

    'Fill the context with the route data, just in case some page needs it
    For Each value In requestContext.RouteData.Values
        HttpContext.Current.Items(value.Key) = value.Value
    Next

    Dim VirtualPath As String
    VirtualPath = "~/" + requestContext.RouteData.Values("page") + ".aspx"

    Dim redirectPage As IHttpHandler
    redirectPage = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath, GetType(Page))
    Return redirectPage

  End Function
End Class
```

Finally I use the default.aspx in the root to redirect to the default lang used in the browser list.
Maybe this can be done with the route.Defaults, but don't work inside Visual Studio (maybe it works in the server)

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim DefaultLang As String = "es"
    Dim SupportedLangs As String() = {"en", "es"}
    Dim BrowserLang As String = Mid(Request.UserLanguages(0).ToString(), 1, 2).ToLower
    If SupportedLangs.Contains(BrowserLang) Then DefaultLang = BrowserLang

    Response.Redirect(DefaultLang + "/")
End Sub
```

Some sources:
  * [Mike Ormond's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikeormond/archive/2008/05/14/using-asp-net-routing-independent-of-mvc.aspx)
  * [Chris Cavanagh’s Blog](http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2008/04/25/systemwebrouting-with-webforms-sample/)
  * [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add that parameter

```
http://yoursite/yourPage.aspx?lang=en-US
```

If you were utilizing resources files it will work automatically.

Good Luck