# Writing ASP.NET web forms Application URL like ASP.NET MVC (that uses Razor) URL

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to redecorate URLs that I am using in my ASP.NET Web Forms application to be like Asp.net MVC apps that uses razor , the first step I've done is to remove the aspx successor and I am done with this but the second step is which I am trying is to replace pagename?id=someid with pagename/id
or any formula except the usual formula , tbh the task eventually is to reduce the characters used in the ULR so removing .aspx will execlude 4 characters and the second approach will replace ?id= with slash
and renaming page with pagename+id like n1 will not hit the server as the page name would have been changed

I did the below change on my web.config to exclude aspx successor

```
<system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="RewriteASPX">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update! I am able to find semi solution after few hours of searching and testing ,
I called it semi solution because ajax calls is no longer working , and any page that has update panel is showing error related to axd ,I used routing as the link below

[ASP.NET Routing with Web Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174849/asp-net-routing-with-web-forms)

just added the below code  to global.asax file

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
        void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
               routes.MapPageRoute(
                "mypage",
                "mypage/{Name}",
                "~/mypage.aspx"
                                  );
         }
```

and on my page I am redirecting as:

```
Response.Redirect(GetRouteUrl("mypage", new { Name = "myparam" }));
```

Comment: the above solutions is working but if I have update panel , i have script manager error axd, Uncaught Error: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.